# How to avoid running CI across Github PR/merge queue/pull events when content is unchanged?

Tags: github, github-actions

Imagine I have a Github CI job that I want to run on pull request, merge queue, and pull to main. This process is expensive so I want to avoid any unnecessary runs such that if I run it on a PR and that PR is the only content within the merge then it's a no-op and the CI job isn't run again. Similar for the main push, if this content has been CI'd before don't run it again. I want to maintain the CI task on all three locations to catch the case where folks have bypassed the PR checks and pushed to main.

I've played about a bit where I set up my workflow to store, via `actions/cache` the results of CI runs against the sha of the most recent commit but hashes in PR aren't guaranteed to be the same after merge to main so using the commit sha as a cache key won't work. Short of hashing all of the content under test myself is there anything within the GitHub events I could key off of across PR, merge, and pull that would allow me to cache these results successfully?

Comment: You could use the Git tree hash instead of the commit hash, which you get with `commit^{tree}`, like `HEAD^{tree}` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtlttypegtemegemv0998commitem))?